# How to solve duplicate metric reporting issues in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have an application that reports some kind of database aggregate as metrics on its metric endpoint. When this service is running in K8s, each pod starts emitting the same metrics and since the metric being reported is a database aggregate, it remains more or less the same for a period of time. From Prometheus' point of view, each pod is reporting the metric with a unique pod name label, so it considers these metrics as independent. When we plot those metrics in graphs, we see multiple lines for the same label for the same absolute value, because those are emitted by different pods.

How do we solve this problem for K8s based deployments? One option is to have a separate service running with just one pod reporting that metric but that seems like an overkill.

Comment: did you check an option to set-up exporter for your DB? https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/

Comment: @star67 I'm looking for Couchbase and these reporters report the server metrics, but I'm trying to emit business query related metrics.